Coil cache image not working in Jetpack Compose
I use OkHttp to cache API request and save result in ViewModel. After that I using AsyncImage with that data saved in that ViewModel. But when I using Coil 2.6.0 to cache, I encounter a problem:
When there is network connection, the images are loading fine. However, when there is no network connection, the images are not being pulled from the cache as I expected them, it using default image instead.
Here's a block of code I have.
In UI Compose:
 val imageUrl = searchViewModel.listEvent.item[index].content?.image
 Log.d("TienDM", "imageUrl $imageUrl") // I logged has data link image
 val listener = object : ImageRequest.Listener {
    override fun onError(request: ImageRequest, result: ErrorResult) {
       Log.d("TienDM", "Coil cache image failed") // I turn off network, this line not occurs 
          super.onError(request, result)
       }

    override fun onSuccess(request: ImageRequest, result: SuccessResult) {
        Log.d("TienDM", "Coil cache image success")
        super.onSuccess(request, result)
    }
}
    val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(imageUrl)
        .listener(listener)
        .memoryCacheKey(imageUrl)
        .diskCacheKey(imageUrl)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.image_faztaa_app)
        .error(R.drawable.image_faztaa_app)
        .fallback(R.drawable.image_faztaa_app)
        .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .crossfade(true)
        .build()

    SubcomposeAsyncImage(
        model = imageRequest
    )

In ViewModel
 private fun loadImageEvent() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .cache(Cache(File(context.cacheDir, "http-cache"), 1L * 1024L * 1024L)) // 1 MiB
                .addNetworkInterceptor(cacheInterceptor) // only if Cache-Control header is not enabled from the server
                .addInterceptor(forceCacheInterceptor)
                .build()
            val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("/event/list")
                .build()
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    Log.d("TienDM", "get api failed")
                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val stringBody = response.body?.string()
                        Log.d("TienDM", "get api success $stringBody")
                        stringBody?.let {
                            try {
                                val events = Gson().fromJson<List<ResponseEventList>>(stringBody, object : TypeToken<List<ResponseEventList>>() {}.type)
                                _listEvent.update { events }
                            } catch (_: JsonSyntaxException) {
                            } catch (_: JsonSyntaxException) {
                            } catch (_: IllegalStateException) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
       

Config in Application
  override fun newImageLoader(): ImageLoader {
        return ImageLoader.Builder(this)
            .components {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
                } else{
                    add(GifDecoder.Factory())
                }
            }
            .crossfade(true)
            .bitmapConfig(bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .memoryCache {
                MemoryCache.Builder(this)
                    .maxSizePercent(0.1)
                    .weakReferencesEnabled(true)
                    .build()
            }
            .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .diskCache {
                DiskCache.Builder()
                    .directory(File(cacheDir,"image_cache").apply { mkdirs() })
                    .maxSizePercent(0.001)
                    .build()
            }
            .logger(DebugLogger())
            .build()
    }

I have other question: override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) { always called (Log.d("TienDM", "Coil cache image success")), although I have turn on or turn off network. Therefore I wonder that API called again? The data in ViewModel I logged is always success and is a list.
